# How can I concisely document methods in Perl code?

Tags: perl, perldoc, dist-zilla, perl-pod

I favor a kind-of literal programming style with POD comments next to the code they document. Unfortunately this bloats the code, which is not very Perlish ;-) The best way I could find by now is to use [Dist::Zilla](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Dist%3a%3aZilla) with [Pod::Weaver](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Pod%3a%3aWeaver) like that:

```
package Foo;
#ABSTRACT: Foobar helper module for Foos

=method foo ( $bar, $doz )

Lorem ipsum hopladi and hoplada.

=cut

sub foo {
   ...
}
```

One could argue to remove empty lines but this also decreases readability. Isn't there a way to write more concise without any repeating and unnecessary syntax like this:

```
package Foo;
#ABSTRACT: Foobar helper module for Foos

#METHOD: Lorem ipsum hopladi and hoplada.
sub foo { # $bar, $doz
   ...
}
```

And get this expanded to full POD:

```
=head1 NAME 

Foo - Foobar helper module for Foos

=head1 METHODS

=head2 foo ( $bar, $doz )

Lorem ipsum hopladi and hoplada.
```

I think it should be possibly with a Pod::Weaver plugin but trying to understand the architecture of Pod::Weaver combined with Dist::Zilla and PPI made my brain hurt :-(

Answer (score 3):

I have used two different implementations (for Perl projects) [Natural Docs](http://www.naturaldocs.org/) and [OODoc](http://search.cpan.org/dist/OODoc/) that are close to your requirement. I do not recommend any of them, simply because I don't like autogenerated documentation regardless of language. Good documentation requires time and efforts, otherwise you end up with a skeleton of documentation that is useless.

Comment: Thanks. I'd distinguish documentation in form of explanations and examples (which are usually found in the `DESCRIPTION` and `SYNOPSIS` section in Perl) and documentation of method purpose and calling syntax. The former is essential for good documentation, the latter is just convenient and it can be auto-generated very well.

Answer (score 1):

I will start by asking why do you need so concise documentation statements?

I have used Natural Docs, and I really like it. 
My style of documentation is not concise but I find it readable.
Example:

```
=begin nd

Check if a document name is available.

A name is available iff the name is not used by any other document related to the same study
excepted if it is another version of the same document.

Params:
    name        - Proposed document name to be checked : Str.
    study       - the study related to the document
    parent      -  parent document or undef if none : <Document>
    current_instance - the curretn document instance in case of an update


Returns:
    true iff the proposed name is valid

Exception:
    Dies on bad args or errors.

=cut
```

Natural Docs is able to automatically pick the function or method name.
Moreover I use it to document my javascript sources and global documentation, and can insert cross-links between them.

Comment: If I document a method in much detail, the brevity does not matter, but in some cases one sentence and a list of parameters is enough. I only ask for this case.